# jquery if list equal 1 remove buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want if list equal 1 remove buttons,

Remove buttons from ID count 1 list,

If have another ID count > 1 don't remove buttons,

Using jQuery,

```
var $this = jQuery(this);
var $getList = jQuery('#count li');
var $sliderButtons = jQuery('#count .slider_next, #count .slider_prev');
if($getList.length == 1){
    $sliderButtons.remove();
};
```

I code want to working with only list == 1 remove buttons

```
    <div id="count">
        <ul id="sldr">
           <li>if equal 1 list, remove buttons.</li>
        </ul>
        <i class="slider_next"></i>
        <i class="slider_prev"></i>
    </div>

    <div id="count">
        <ul id="sldr">
           <li>if equal > 1 list, don't remove buttons.</li>
           <li>hello</li>
        </ul>
        <i class="slider_next"></i>
        <i class="slider_prev"></i>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the basic HTML as well

Comment: Why do I ask? Becuase your code basically works: http://jsfiddle.net/mqd5bacs/ If it is not working for you the HTML does not match the selectors.

Comment: First problem, ID must be unique on a page.

Comment: Yeah I included jQuery

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".count ul") 
   .filter(function( index ) {
       return $( "li", this ).length === 1;
    })
   .closest(".count")
   .find("i").remove();
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mqd5bacs/2/)

We are using `.filter()` and the function inside to restrict the set of `ul` elements to those with only one `li`. Then `closest(".count")` gets the `.count` parent of the `ul`. Next find and remove the `i` tags.

You will also need to remove duplicate IDs in your HTML and replace with a class. Something like:

```
<div class="count">
    <ul class="sldr">
       <li>if equal > 1 list, don't remove buttons.</li>
       <li>hello</li>
    </ul>
    <i class="slider_next">n</i>
    <i class="slider_prev">p</i>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

I made a jsbin for you: http://jsbin.com/qumuraqijaqu/1/edit?html,js,output

Try removing some of the `li` elements, and you'll see it works.

Here is the solution:

```
if($getList.length == 1){
    $sliderButtons.each(function(index,item){
      item.remove();
    });
};
```

Instead of calling `remove()` on the `$sliderButtons` variable, we instead loop through each element, and run the code inside of our call back for it. We then individually run `remove()` on each element in the `$sliderButtons` variable.

Comment: not working with 2 ul